# Modulus arithmetic / multiplicative order question

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm working on a problem about shuffling decks, using https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Out-Shuffle.html

So I need to find all deck sizes $n$ where you can shuffle (using out-shuffle) so that it returns to the original order in a given number $k$ shuffles.

What I've gathered, after help from the friendly folks here at Math Stack Exchange, is that I need to factorize the following, for my given $k$:

$$
2^{k}  \equiv  1 \mod (n-1)
$$

i.e factorize for

$$
2^{k} - 1
$$

For $k=8$, I know from a brute-force attempt, that the correct list of deck sizes should be:

$$
[18, 52, 86, 256]
$$

How do I go from the above formulas to all the divisors, to this list?

Comment: Why $(n-1)$ and not $n$? As for solution, just factor $2^{60}-1$, it is easy.

Comment: @metamorphy Im sorry, I dont understand what you mean by just factoring

Comment: The congruence means that $\ n-1\mid 2^{60}-1\ $, so you just have to find the divisors of $2^{60}-1$

Comment: Thank you everyone! Extremely helpful!

Comment: The problem relates to this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Out-Shuffle.html but I seem to be missing something

Comment: When I test for k=8, ie 2^8 = 1, I get prime factors 3, 5, 17, with solutions for n=[16, 52, 86, 256], which is wrong. I should be getting n=[18, 52, 86, 256]..

Comment: ok, sorry, I will make an edit

Comment: Why are you leaving the single primes $+ 1$ out of your  list? The $18$ is $\ 17+1\ $, and divisors of $\ 2^8-1\ $ are $\ 1, $$3, $$5, $$17,$$ 3\times5,$$ 3\times17, $$5\times17\ $ and $\ 3\times5\times17\ $, omitting the unit $1$ and adding $1$ to the rest of those numbers gives you $\ 4,$$6,$$18,$$16,$$52,$$86\ $, and $256$.  Why do you omit $\ 4, 6\ $ and $\ 18\ $ from your original list (and $\ 4, 6\ $ and $16$ from what you apparently regard as the "correct" list)?  And why do think that *is* the "correct" list?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera the correct list of deck sizes should be correct because I've run a more naive brute force solution with k=8 and it gives me this list of deck sizes. Problem is I cant run it for very large k's

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Not sure why I'm leaving out 1s, could be because I'm using a fast prime factorization algorithm I found which does it..

Comment: You ask for what you did wrong but you don't show us what you did for us to check...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Im sorry, I thought it would be enough to show my thought process

Comment: Previously you had said you had gotten something else and asked for what you did wrong, yet I did not see any explanation of your thought process on how you had gotten what you did.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I edited the original question to try to clarify what I want to do, which is to figure out how to get that correct list n's from that modular arithmetic formula. I'm sorry if I was unclear before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While *all* divisors $\ d\ $ of $\ 2^8-1\ $ will satisfy the congruence $\ 2^8\equiv$$ 1\pmod{d}\ $ , you only want the ones for which $8$ is the *order* of $2 \pmod{d}\ $—i.e. those which do not divide $\ 2^2-1=3\ $ or $\ 2^4-1=15\ $.  So, from the list of non-unit divisors $\ 3,$$5,$$17,$$15,$$51,$$85,$ and $255$, of $\ 2^8-1\ $ you have to eliminate $\ 3,$$5,$ and $15$, leaving $17,$$51,$$85$ and $255$, which gives you your list of $18,$$52,$$86,$ and $256$ as the possible values for $\  n\ $.

More generally, after getting all the divisors $\ d\ $ of $\ 2^k-1\ $, you need to eliminate any which divide $\ 2^r-1\ $ for any factor $\ r<k\ $ of $\ k\ $.

Comment: Thanks for that very thorough explanation. Still a bit confused, as 3 divides 51..

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out :) Thank you thank you thank you!